# Is there a way to test insufficient card balance through sandbox?

Tags: square-connect

Is there a way to test insufficient card balance through SquareUp sandbox account?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

No. An explicit purpose of the sandbox environment is to not interact with actual payment systems.

Comment: ok, sorry being so noob here :) can i ask what is the return status for insufficient balance or no balance for actual payments?

Comment: Take a look at the docs: https://docs.connect.squareup.com you shoukd be able to find all the response types for the platform you are using.